# how to validate data being entered in pop-up from a gridview in devexpress

Tags: gridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a gridview setup in DevExpress so that when I want to add an item to the grid, I have an edit form that pops up.  I want to validate the data that I enter in the pop-up form.

I'm using the `ValidatingEditor` method because I want to make sure
that columns that are number fields, only accept numbers and
columns that accept string fields, only accept strings.

I'm trying to do to access the value that has been edited by doing this:

```
gvTaxes.ActiveEditor.EditValue.ToString()
```

So this would be the

```
Private Sub gvTaxes_ValidatingEditor(sender As Object, e As BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs) Handles gvTaxes.ValidatingEditor

    Dim strCurrentValue As String

    If Not IsDBNull(gvTaxes.ActiveEditor.EditValue.ToString()) Then

        strCurrentValue = gvTaxes.ActiveEditor.EditValue.ToString()

    End If
```

I get a NullReferenceException exception from the 'if' line.  Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `e.Value.ToString()` instead of `gvTaxes.ActiveEditor.EditValue.ToString()` :

```
If Not IsDBNull(e.Value.ToString()) Then

    strCurrentValue = e.Value.ToString()

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your gvTaxes_ValidatingEditor :

```
Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim d As Double
    Dim strCurrentValue As String
    If view.FocusedColumn.FieldName = "YourColumnName" Then

        If Not Double.TryParse(Convert.ToDouble(e.Value).ToString(), d) Then
            e.Valid = False
            e.ErrorText = "the input value is invalid !"
        Else

            strCurrentValue = e.Value.ToString()
        End If
    End If
```